# Restricted pages with client side templating

Tags: java, javascript, security, templates, angularjs

We've always used server side templates ( .JSP ) for web apps but now we're using Angular for a big project. It starts making sense to use client side templates, although some security questions have risen...

Is it possible at all to prevent the user from accessing a certain template that should only be viewed if he is logged in? Seems easy enough to just hack it away using developer tools or firebug..

A way to control this, would be to return the view from the server, but wouldn't I loose all the goodies from Angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the framework you can restrict this from the server and you would not loose any Angular goodies.

The way you include templates into Angular is by either using `ng-view` or `ng-include`.

`ng-view` template is configure during the route definition. Since these templates are loaded from server you can always control loading of these template.

`ng-include` too can take server side templates, and the same restriction can be enforced using AngularJS.

We use ASP.Net MVC so in ASP.Net you can put `AuthorizeAttribute` over the controller (server side) method that returns the view to controller what get's returned to client.

Also keep in mind, once a template is loaded it would be cached by Angular's template cache so it would not be fetched until the page is refresh (browser navigation \ F5)

Comment: Thanks, after a little research it sounds like i should be using Spring security to match the AuthorizeAttribute from ASP.Net. I'll see if i can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

One thought, you could leverage [$cookie](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookies) and $cookieStorage Angular API.

Authenticated users would have a special value in the cookie. Then you could add a check in your specific Controllers, to see if the value exists, it not - restrict or redirect to a different view for authentication.

Comment: sounds like it could work, unfortunately i cannot use cookies because of a rule issued in my country.

Comment: wow. this I was not aware. is it that the policy restricts storing info in the cookie or cookies itself are not permitted.

Comment: supposedly its regarding the information contained in them, since this is a banking application the rules are stricter and its a subject we don't really want to go into with clients. They seem to be scared of it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming someone is crafty enough, it can be difficult to prevent the templates themselves from being seen.  When you load the main login page, I am assuming that your server will provide the complete Angular Javascript single-page application.  The crafty person can look through the loaded Javascript to determine the routes and then make explicit calls to download those templates outside the Angular app.  I think most Angular apps are just making the templates Publicly accessible.  In that case, all someone needs to know is the template name to get to them.

While that sounds a bit scary, the good thing is that the data populating the templates should be much easier to secure.  If you are getting your data from a service running on the server, then you can make sure the user is actually logged in (and has the proper role) before providing the data.

This means that it is probably easy for a crafty person to get the empty template, but if security is done correctly on the server then it should be difficult for them to get data to populate that template.

This page has some good examples on how to apply security to an AngularJS app:  http://frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/